# my SpringBoot container can't contact my Postgres container in minikube cluster

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kubernetes, containers, minikube

i built a little stack in a minikube cluster with :

- a java spring-boot application into a Pod/Container
- a postgres databse into a Pod/Container

the spring boot application has to reach spring boot container but it doesn't.
Postgres container seems to start correctly ("")
but spring boot container does not. At start, i have a message like :

```
Could not obtain connection to query metadata : HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
```

So i'd like to learn debugging this kind of problem, because i don't know to deal with this error

-is it a network issue ? (pod can't be contacted ?)
-is it a credentials issue ?

- other ?

(pod can't be contacted ?)

Comment: It's a network issue.  Undoubtedly.

Comment: please show your manifests for pods and services

Comment: The value of the `spring.datasource.url` property is also probably relevant.  (I'd set it via an environment variable in the Deployment manifest, but you might have it somewhere else.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, all is ok now. The mistake I made was that I believed I had built the new image, but I kept building it with the same tag. So, the image changed on DockerHub, but the cluster never pulled the new content of the image, because the tagged version had been cached.

When building with a tag N+1, kubernetes then pulled the N+1 version and the pods were started successfully.

My new rule: new docker build --> new tag !!!